# Making sum on join tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a Rails 3.2 web app.
In this app I got four tables. Project, Task, Article and Item.

What I want to do is to get all the task values (prices from article) summed up
in a single call.

This is what I tried and it works, but is it the best way of doing it?

```
@project.tasks.where("status = ?", "completed").joins(:articles).sum(:price)
```

**Task table**

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base

 has_many :articles
 has_many :items, :through => :articles

end
```

**Article Join Table**

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :task
 belongs_to :item

 attr_accessible :account_id, :amount, :price, :item_id, :task_id

end
```

**Item table**

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base

 has_many :articles
 has_many :tasks, :through => :articles

end
```

Comment: You should look at the SQL query generated but I think it's the fastest (query-time-wise) solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to sum it up it looks ok the way you did it, but also you can prettify your code:

**project.rb**

```
has_many :completed_tasks, class: 'Task', :conditions => {:status => 'completed'}
```

**controller**

```
@project.completed_tasks.joins(:articles).sum(:price)
```